# How do I get my text to align my picture?

Tags: html, css

This is the look:

[image]

How do I move the text up? So its centered besides the image?

CSS:

```
header{
padding: 20px;
background-color: #34495e;
color: black;
}
.header-1{
 color: white;
padding: 0px 190px;
font-size: 17px;
vertical-align: middle;
line-height: 20px;
}
.logopng{
width: 35px;
height: 35px;
}
```

HTML:

```
 <header>
 <div class="header-1">
 <img src="http://i.imgur.com/cGlBmw7.png" class="logopng">
 Rocket League Prices
 </div>
 </header>
```

EDIT: added vertical-align:middle to the image class

Comment: Fixed, added "vertical-align:middle" to the image class.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to set `display: flex` and `align-items: center` on parent element.

```css
header {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #34495e;
  color: black;
}
.header-1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 17px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.logopng {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="header-1">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/cGlBmw7.png" class="logopng">Rocket League Prices
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use **css3 flexbox** concept.just add

```
display:flex;
align-items:center;
justify-content:center;
```

to your `.header-1` it works fine.I'm added the snippet below.

```css
header{
padding: 20px;
background-color: #34495e;
color: black;
}
.header-1{
 color: white;
  font-size: 17px;
  display:flex;
 align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
.logopng{
width: 35px;
height: 35px;
  margin-right:10px;
}
```

```html
<header>
 <div class="header-1">
 <img src="http://i.imgur.com/cGlBmw7.png" class="logopng">
 Rocket League Prices
 </div>
 </header>
```